# Problemas com new em Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Por que toda vez que eu uso `new` na minha classe, por exemplo:

```
if(e.getSource() == levelButton) {
     new PainelNivel().setVisible(true);
}
```

O Java executa esse comando ou seja, mostra a classe **PainelNivel** e abre a classe da onde esse comando foi executado. Agora, por que isso acontece?

OBS: Já fiz esse mesmo procedimento no "construtor de *JFrame's*" do **Netbeans** e deu certo. Por que agora não está dando?

```
package main;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

// Variáveis

JButton generateButton = new JButton("Gerar outro número");
JButton testButton = new JButton("Verificar");
JButton levelButton = new JButton("Nível");
private final JLabel label = new JLabel("Digite um número de 1 a 1000.");
JTextField campotext = new JTextField(27);
private final Object[] ops = new Object[3];

private int i, limit, num, palp, c;

// Construtor
public Window() {
    super("Adivinha Número 1.0");
    setSize(420, 120);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    add(label);
    add(campotext);
    add(testButton);
    add(generateButton);
    add(levelButton);
    testButton.addActionListener(this);
    generateButton.addActionListener(this);
    levelButton.addActionListener(this);

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    Generate();
}

// Gerador
private void Generate() {
    Random gen = new Random();
    num = gen.nextInt(1001);
}

// Teste
private void Test(int palp) {

    if(palp < num) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Errou, o número é maior");
    } else if(palp > num) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Errou, o número é menor");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Parabéns, voce acertou o numero!");
        campotext.setEditable(false);
    }
}

public int SetLimit(int l) {

    this.limit = l;
    return l;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == testButton) {
        palp = Integer.parseInt(campotext.getText());
        Test(palp);

    if(i == limit) {

        ops[0] = "Fechar";
        ops[1] = "Gerar Outro Número";
        ops[2] = "Mudar Nível";

        c = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "Você chegou ao limite de   tentativas!", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, ops, ops[0]);

    if(c == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if(c == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        Generate();
        campotext.setText("");
        i = 0;
    } else if(c == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        new PainelNivel().setVisible(true);
    }

    } else {
        i++;
        System.out.println("Contador = " + i);
    }
}

    if(e.getSource() == generateButton) {
            Generate();
            campotext.setEditable(true);
            campotext.setText("");
            i = 0;
            System.out.println("Contador = " + i);
        }

    if(e.getSource() == levelButton) {
            new PainelNivel().setVisible(true);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
}
 }
```

Código da classe **PainelNivel**:

```
package main;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class PainelNivel extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

private Window w = new Window();

private final JLabel inst = new JLabel("Selecione o nível de dificuldade:");
private final JButton f = new JButton("Fácil (50 Tentativas)");
private final JButton m = new JButton("Médio (30 Tentativas)");
private final JButton d = new JButton("Difícil (10 Tentativas)");

public PainelNivel() {
    setTitle("Seletor De Nível");
    setSize(270, 160);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(w);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    add(inst);
    add(f);
    add(m);
    add(d);
    f.addActionListener(this);
    m.addActionListener(this);
    d.addActionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == f) {
        w.SetLimit(50);
        dispose();
    } else if(e.getSource() == m) {
        w.SetLimit(30);
        dispose();
    } else if (e.getSource() == d) {
        w.SetLimit(10);
        dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

*printStackTrace* > **PainelNivel**:

```
java.lang.Throwable: Printing stack trace:
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.printStackTrace(Utility.java:933)
at main.Window.<init>(Window.java:48)
at main.PainelNivel.<init>(PainelNivel.java:13)
at main.Window.actionPerformed(Window.java:116)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at      javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
java.lang.Throwable: Printing stack trace:
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.util.Utility.printStackTrace(Utility.java:933)
at main.PainelNivel.<init>(PainelNivel.java:36)
at main.Window.actionPerformed(Window.java:116)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste seu exemplo você está tentando criar uma instância de `PainelNivel` e chamando para esta instância o método [`setVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible-boolean-).

> Já fiz esse mesmo procedimento no "construtor de JFrame's" do Netbeans e deu certo. Por que agora não está dando?

Por `Já fiz esse mesmo procedimento no...` você deve estar falando que conseguiu usar [`setVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setVisible-boolean-) em uma instância de [`JFrame`][jframe.

Bem, isto deu certo com [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) por que ele tem este método, uma vez que é uma subclasse de [`Window`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) que é uma subclasse de [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) (obs.: todos que de alguma forma extendem de [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) possuem tal método).

Se para `PainelNivel` está dando erro, isto é por que `PainelNivel` não é, de alguma forma, uma subclasse de [`Component`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html).

Observação:

> o java executa esse comando ou seja, mostra a classe PainelNível e abre a classe da onde esse comando foi executado. Agora, por que isso acontece?

Na verdade não é que O java executa este comando, mostra a classe e abre a classe de onde esse comando foi executado. [`new`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) é uma palavra chave e reservada na linguagem para criar instâncias e a classe é mostrada pelo o IDE (no seu caso o Netbeans) por que ele está te dando uma mãozinha e listando as classes no classpath do seu projeto. Há outras observações no seu texto, mas enfim, isto é para depois =)

Caso o meu entendimento esteja errado, só falar =D

**EDIT:**

Bom, considerando os comentários, o entendimento inicial acima é completamente diferente do problema, até mesmo devido ao texto inicial da pergunta.

Bom, seu programa possui diversos problemas, não irei citar todos e nem mesmo refatorá-lo todo, mas apenas destacar pontos que fizeram com que o erro não mais aparecesse, pelo menos por aqui.

Primeiro: você está criando `N` instância de de `PainelNivel`. Até onde entendi não há necessidade disto, uma vez que você pode apenas torná-lo visível. Então, crie uma variável em `Window` assim:

```
private final PainelNivel painel = new PainelNivel();
```

Além disto, também na classe `Window`, onde possuir `new PainelNivel().setVisible(true);`, substitua por `painel.setVisible(true);`. Por último, ainda na classe `PainelNivel`, altere de:

```
private Window w = new Window();
```

para:

```
private static Window w;
```

e inclua o método `main` em `PainelNivel`:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    w = new Window();
}
```

Segundo: você também está criando mais instâncias de `Window` que o necessário. Como uma forma de evitar isto já passamos para `PainelNivel` a responsabilidade de controlar o ciclo de vida da única instância de `Window` (obs.: essa pode não ser a melhor solução, mas devido a forma que está, ou seja, a propriedade `limit`, para simplificar fiz assim) e mudamos um pouco o fluxo da aplicação.

Por último, remova da classe `PainelNivel`

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    w = new Window();
}
```

Realizadas as alterações acima e algumas outras para você dar uma olhada, no meu ambiente a classe `PainelNivel` ficou assim:

```
public class PainelNivel extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1793309720800631003L;

    private static Window window;

    private final JLabel lblSelecioneNivel = new JLabel("Selecione o nível de dificuldade:");
    private final JButton btnFacil = new JButton("Fácil (50 Tentativas)");
    private final JButton btnMedio = new JButton("Médio (30 Tentativas)");
    private final JButton btnDificil = new JButton("Difícil (10 Tentativas)");

    public PainelNivel() {
        setTitle("Seletor De Nível");
        setSize(270, 160);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(window);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(lblSelecioneNivel);
        add(btnFacil);
        add(btnMedio);
        add(btnDificil);
        btnFacil.addActionListener(this);
        btnMedio.addActionListener(this);
        btnDificil.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnFacil) {
            window.setLimit(50);
            dispose();
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnMedio) {
            window.setLimit(30);
            dispose();
        } else if (e.getSource() == btnDificil) {
            window.setLimit(10);
            dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        window = new Window();
    }

}
```

E a classe `Window` ficou assim:

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1096933824629421772L;

    private final PainelNivel painel = new PainelNivel();

    private final JButton btnGerarNumero = new JButton("Gerar outro número");
    private final JButton btnVerificar = new JButton("Verificar");
    private final JButton btnNivel = new JButton("Nível");
    private final JLabel lblDigiteNumero = new JLabel("Digite um número de 1 a 1000.");
    private final JTextField txtFieldNumero = new JTextField(27);
    private final Object[] dialogOpcoes = {"Fechar", "Gerar Outro Número", "Mudar Nível"};

    private int tentativas, qtdTentativas, numeroAleatorio, palpite, c;

    public Window() {
        super("Adivinha Número 1.0");
        setSize(420, 120);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(lblDigiteNumero);
        add(txtFieldNumero);
        add(btnVerificar);
        add(btnGerarNumero);
        add(btnNivel);
        btnVerificar.addActionListener(this);
        btnGerarNumero.addActionListener(this);
        btnNivel.addActionListener(this);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        generate();
    }

    private void generate() {
        final Random gen = new Random();
        numeroAleatorio = gen.nextInt(1001);
    }

    private void testePalpite(final int palp) {
        if (palp < numeroAleatorio) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Errou, o número é maior");
        } else if (palp > numeroAleatorio) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Errou, o número é menor");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Parabéns, voce acertou o numero!");
            txtFieldNumero.setEditable(false);
        }
    }

    public void setLimit(final int limit) {
        qtdTentativas = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnVerificar) {
            palpite = Integer.parseInt(txtFieldNumero.getText());
            testePalpite(palpite);

            if (tentativas == qtdTentativas) {
                c = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "Você chegou ao limite de tentativas!", "Game Over",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, dialogOpcoes,
                        dialogOpcoes[0]);

                if (c == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    dispose();
                } else if (c == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                    generate();
                    txtFieldNumero.setText("");
                    tentativas = 0;
                } else if (c == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                    painel.setVisible(true);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Tentativas já realizadas = " + ++tentativas);
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == btnGerarNumero) {
            generate();
            txtFieldNumero.setEditable(true);
            txtFieldNumero.setText("");
            tentativas = 0;
            System.out.println("Tentativas já realizadas = " + tentativas);
        }

        if (e.getSource() == btnNivel) {
            System.out.println("Alteração de nível solicitada.");
            painel.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Não me foi apresetanda a mensagem de erro, caso continue acontecendo contigo, informe-me os passos para reproduzir =)

Comment: Bom, PainelNivel é um JDialog, e pelo que eu sei JDialog e sim uma subclasse de Component, certo? Para esclarecer vou postar o código da casse PainelNivel na resposta, ok?

Comment: Sim @Dongabi. Então, por favor, atualize sua pergunta com o stack trace do erro e mais informações sobre `PainelNivel`. Obrigado.

Comment: Pronto! - @Bruno_César

Comment: Tá meio difícil entender o que você tá fazendo jovem. Você tem uma classe `Window`, que trata alguns eventos e em algum evento cria uma instância de `PainelNivel`, certo? Em `PainelNivel` tu cria um `Window` e fala que a instância de `PainelNivel` é relativa à instância de `Window`? o_O, cara, que loucura, tá difícil entender o fluxo do da sua aplicação. Poste a classe `Window` para ver se consigo entender melhor rs

Comment: Pronto - @Bruno_César

Comment: @Dongabi editei a resposta considerando alguns pontos, veja se contigo funciona também. Bons estudos :)

Comment: Po vey, valeu mesmo! deu certo! É que eu tô começando agora, sabe?... Mais valeu brother! :D

Comment: Que isso cara, precisando só valor.